# Amplify Cloudformation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

My understanding of Amplify is that on `amplify push`, it somehow processes the separate cloudformation templates for each service (including the parameters.json) and deploys the app. Where does this "master" cloudformation template get stored. For example in the API resource, there is an api-params.json file specifying the endpoint restrictions based on auth roles, but I do not see those in the api cloudformation template. How would I see the final template with the auth restrictions applied to the API Gateway resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can see your nested Stack and all the templates in the AWS Console -> CloudFormation.
2. You can see the templates in your code repository locally after performing `amplify pull` in the amplify/backend/#current-cloud-backend
3. You can see the templates stored in S3 in your deployment bucket e.g., `s3://amplify-appName-envName-someId-deployment/amplify-cfn-templates`

Comment: The template shown in the cloudformation template is the same as in the amplify folder. I was looking for settings that restrict access to API Gateway (I see the settings in api-params.json in the amplify folder), but those aren't in the template. I see some of the user group roles initialized in the parameters section of the template but the parameters aren't referenced anywhere else in the api template. Where can I find this?

Comment: I see the roles and restrictions now but they don't reference the parameters initialized at the top of the template which threw me off. Thanks